# "I will be there before you."

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Does this sentence make sense, and does it mean that you will reach a place earlier than someone else? Or would you have to say "ahead of you" or the aforementioned "earlier than you"?

> I will be there before you.

Answer (score 7):

*before you* makes sense and is completely idiomatic, probably more idiomatic than "I'll be there earlier than you".  [One of the meanings of *before* is "at an earlier time"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before), and this is an example of using the word in that sense.

In fact, ["I'll be in Scotland before you" is part of the lyrics of a famous song.](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=4766584)  (It's often written and sung as *afore ye*, which is archaic, but the words and meaning are essentially the same.)

Comment: Is it Scottish English or is it Scots? Not convinced even a Glaswegian would say "afore ye" these days...

Comment: @Muzer The rendition of _The Bonnie Banks of Loch Lomond_ [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bonnie_Banks_o%27_Loch_Lomond#Lyrics) renders it "afore ye" but is clearly in English, not Scots. Compare, for example, this [fragment of the New Testament in Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language#Sample_text_of_Modern_Scots).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fair enough. I guess it hardly has to be an accurate representation of modern Scottish English dialect!

Comment: @Muzer Indeed -- it's a traditional song, so the lyrics we know today are probably a mishmash of idioms and edits over hundreds of years. It probably doesn't correspond to the dialect of any specific time, any more.

Comment: @Muzer - just to avoid confusion or misrepresenting anyone, I'm editing my answer.  I thought it was Scottish usage, but what do I know?

Answer (score 6):

> I will get there **before you**
>   I will get there **ahead of you**
>   I will get there **first**

all mean

> I will get there **earlier than you**

and are interchangeable without loss of meaning.

Comment: Hmmm, could it also mean "I will be there [standing] before you"? (Say, part of longer speech: "When that day comes and you face your enemies, I will be there before you". Just wondering about the interchangeability.

Comment: Saying "standing there **before you**" is ambiguous since it could mean either *in terms of time* or *in terms of location*, one might say *in front of you* to remove ambiguity.  In the OP's examples *get there* implies *in terms of time*.

Answer (score -5):

> “I will be there before you **will be there**.”

You are referring to an earlier part in the sentence.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: This is grammatically correct but it's unidiomatic. Nobody would ever say this, unless there was some unusual reason that made them need to spell it out in so much detail.

Comment: Well, that's not the point i'm getting at. It means that, no-one actually says it that way...